# Proof that isomorphisms preserve sentences

Tags: logic

Sorry if my title is not the best.

I'm trying to prove that if $\sigma$ is an $\mathcal{L}_\textbf{A}$ sentence and $h:\textbf{A}\rightarrow\textbf{B}$ is an isomorphism, then $\textbf{A}\vDash\sigma\Leftrightarrow\textbf{B}\vDash h(\sigma)$, where $h(\sigma)$ is obtained from $\sigma$ by simultaneous substitution of each name $\textbf{a}$ of an $\textbf{A}$ element in sigma by the corresponding name $\textbf{h(a)}$ of a $\textbf{B}$ element.

I think the proof is by induction on $\sigma$, but I'm having difficulty understanding how to work out the cases for the quantifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the proof is by induction on $\sigma$. You only have to deal with $\exists$, because $\forall$ is equivalent to $\neg\exists\neg$ and you can treat $\neg$ directly.

Suppose that $\sigma = \exists x\,\tau(x)$. For every name $\mathbf{a}$ of an element in $\mathbf{A}$, $\tau$[$x$ \ $\mathbf{a}$] is a simpler formula, and by the induction hypothesis we have:

$\mathbf{A} \models \tau$[$x$ \ $\mathbf{a}$] $\iff \mathbf{B} \models h(\tau)$[$x$ \ $\mathbf{h(a)}$].

Because $h$ is a bijection, there is an $a\in\mathbf{A}$ with name $\mathbf{a}$ such that the LHS holds, iff there is $b\in\mathbf{B}$ with name $\mathbf{b}$, i.e. $\mathbf{b} = \mathbf{h(a)}$ for some $\mathbf{a}$, such that the RHS holds. So:

$\mathbf{A} \models \exists x\,\tau(x) \iff \mathbf{B} \models \exists x\,h(\tau(x))$.

But $\exists x\,\tau(x) = \sigma$, and $\exists x\,h(\tau(x)) = h(\exists x\,\tau(x)) = h(\sigma)$.